# Why my WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive not called

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have written small example for AlarmManager to work. But my WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive is not called at all. Following is my code, Can you pls find out why its not getting called?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wearable.wearables">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name="com.wearable.wearables.AlarmReceiver" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AlarmActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

WakefulBroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"AlarmReceiver OnReceive called......");
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SchedulingService.class);
        startWakefulService(context,service);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG,"setAlarm called...");
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000,
                60000,
                alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Activity setting Alarm

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_alarm);

        AlarmReceiver alarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
        alarmReceiver.setAlarm(this);

    }

}
```

setAlarm method is calling. My intention is I need to call this wakefulService every 30 secs. Issues are

1. Code is not letting to set 30 secs (allowing only one minute as minimum)
2. WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive() is NOT called at all..

I am struggling with this issue. Can someone help me out with this pls?

Comment: add Context.registerReceiver() to your code

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi where should I register the receiver?

Comment: I think you should add it in your OnCreate() method

Comment: You're setting an `ELAPSED_REALTIME` alarm, but you're passing a "wall clock" time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) for the initial time. Either use an `RTC` alarm, or use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` for the initial time.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks Mike. Now onReceive is called but its not calling WakefulService.. (sorry Found it I did not define my service in my manifest)

Comment: You forgot the `<service>` element in the manifest for `SchedulingService`.

Comment: @MikeM. I put the following code to execute every 30 secs, but its defaulted to 1 min (Anyway can I run it once 30 secs?). alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 30000,
                30000,
                alarmIntent);

Comment: Yep, it'll do that. If you need an interval that short, `AlarmManager` probably isn't what you want to use anyway. You could try using a one-time exact alarm, and setting it again for the desired interval whenever it fires. Do note, however, that newer Android versions are more strict about when and how often alarms can happen, so it might not work. I can't recall the exact details, at the moment. No coffee yet. :)

Comment: @MikeM. Sure.. I would request, please update this thread whenever you can remember those details.. Actually, I need to send sensor data to server every 30 secs from wearable. This should happen all the time. Thats why I chose AlarmManager considering CPU sleep time. Currently, I am using Handler.postDelayed which works perfectly fine but I think it stops when CPU goes to sleep. I want to send all the time irrespective of CPU cycle. Do you recommend anything else?